# Model Replication using Web API and MVC together

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

So I am working on a project and I have a quick simple outline of the "architecture" outlined here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA9QI.png

I'll have a web api project that will contain all of my business and data access logic and then I will have various other items that will call out to the web api service that will return JSON. The other items will be a separate MVC app, a mobile app, and a device out in the field.

Obviously my business models will be the same across all items and I will want consistency when using those models. For example, let's say that I have a model called "User" that represents a user account and it has the fields FirstName, LastName, Username, etc. and for FirstName and LastName I have certain restrictions that I want to apply such as datatype, max length, etc. The model class might look like this below:

```
public class User
{

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Your {0} must be at least {1} characters long")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Your {0} must be no more than {1} characters")]
    public string Username { get; set; }


    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Your {0} must be at least {1} characters long")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Your {0} must be no more than {1} characters")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Your {0} must be at least {1} characters long")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Your {0} must be no more than {1} characters")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

1. Would I duplicate those models in my web api project as well as my MVC app and mobile app? Or is there a better way to pass these properties down from the web api project so there isn't an inconsistency (ie: FirstName field in MVC web app has 100 max length and FirstName field in the mobile app has 80 max length)

2.Is it best to keep the Web API project and MVC Web app project in the same solution and just have the MVC Web app reference the Web API project so they use the same models and attributes? but then we create a dependency between the two and you still have to worry about the device out in the field as well as the mobile app.

Or, is it best to extract the data models into a separate class library project and put all the model definitions with their attributes there?

Or, is there another better solution?

Any insight is helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: With the introduction of `Asp.net vNext`, the `MVC & WebApi` should have been combined. And for the other part of the question, I would do have a separate library of just the models and move all validation to the corresponding solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this

1) Keep the model  user as it is with validation

2) for web api

a) create a separate project for DTO(data transformation object)

b) data mesh between model entities in the business/app service layer and return the data to api controller in the form Data transformation object(which will be just properties and can be data annotated for validation)

3) For mvc

a) Create a separate project for ViewModel

b) data mesh between model entities in the business/app service layer and return the data to mvc controller in the form of viewmodel(which will be just properties and can be data annotated for validation). return the viewmodel object to mvc view.